# Mobile version of Ubuntu for Nokia N97

Tags: phone

This is not a *Ubuntu Touch* related question.

Is there a mobile version of the Ubuntu OS for Nokia N97?.

If there is:

- How to install it?.
- Where to download it?.
- How to set preferences?.
- Is there a "Ubuntu apps store"? (Not the *Ubuntu Software Center* , I mean apps for mobile phones, including touch screen games and that kind of stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No actually there is no Mobile OS available right now for Nokia Phones.
Ubuntu will be supported for Android devices. 
And right now the Ubuntu touch is available only on Google Nexus Devices.
Yes, there is an app store in Ubuntu touch. It is new, so it will take some time to include maximum number of apps.

Ubuntu and Android need different hardware than Nokia phones and forcefully installing other OS in Nokia devices can brick your device. There is nothing in development for Nokia because they don't allow other OS to be installed in Nokia.